# How to get Autocad working with Wine?

Tags: wine, 3d, blender, winetricks

I am trying 3 years now installing **Autocad**,**3ds Max** and **Revit** architecture on Ubuntu with wine!

Every year I am very optimistic 'cause I see the new wine versions already improved.

So, now I am starting again in a clean Ubuntu installation to install Autocad 2013 with wine 1.4. I am not trying to have an answer only for me, but I want this community to try and finally we can achieve that!

The *winetricks* have already *net framework 4* to install which is the reason I have not already ran to the past Autocad.

So, I would like to remove completely my windows 7 partition from my pc and go on a linux machine without loosing the powerfull architectural programms.I know all about **Blender** and staff so I just want you to help find a solution on that, because I know there is a solution!

Maybe I will have to learn all the *c++* or *python* etc. But I am sure that a solution can come with the help of all of us!

Any suggestion about this problem will be very nice and helpfull.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what the question here is, but I'd like to suggest you to try slightly older versions of software since the newer versions may use APIs not yet fully implemented in Wine. Also, a good place to look for people interested in running, say, AutoCAD under Wine would be Wine's AppDB: http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=86

Comment: ok!So should i not write here about this?I just want someone to take place on this!Sorry but what is API?

Comment: @gabriel - if you are looking for an updated answer - I would recommend you unaccept the current answer otherwise it appears this question has been resolved.  Thanks.

Comment: @gabriel - is there such a thing as AutoCad trialware that we can try to install and help you out.  I note the price for the full version is huge!

Comment: @fossfreedom well you can download any trial version or a student version if someone is..thanks!i want certainly some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to ask in a WINE specific community - the reason for that is in the last paragraph of this answer. I also suggest to re-phrase, re-formant and change this question to a community wiki.

> ok!So should i not write here about this?I just want someone to take place on this!Sorry but what is API? – gabriel Apr 12 at 23:52

Questions regarding *Running third-party applications on Ubuntu* are perfectly valid as stated in [faq](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions).

API (in this context) is a set of instructions (or, more accurately, calls) which a Windows developer uses (more or less directly) to communicate with the operating system from within the application. This set is specific to Windows. What normally WINE does is an attempt to "translate" a *Windows-only* call to a native GNU/Linux call. When such call cannot be easily translated it has to be reimplemented by WINE developers to suite it's original purpose but stay strict with GNU/Linux standards. Many of those calls are just stubs (as in: a call exists but rarely any programmer uses it so it's there but does nothing for now).

> Maybe I will have to learn all the c++ or python etc. But I am sure that a solution can come with the help of all of us!

Although WINE should allow AutoCAD (or any other app) to communicate with GNU/Linux as it does with Windows and still get the proper results (so it would work seamlessly), the majority of the Windows (at least XP) API calls has already been implemented or stubbed and the problem still persists. Most probably AutoCAD uses some exotic (or new) API call (or calls) that yet needs to be implemented. Percentage of WINE community are enthusiasts who can trace this exact calls the application in question crashes on and simply contribute a patch (which you can help to test). You can either keep asking about this in communities like askubuntu.com (which are more related to Ubuntu than WINE development) and hope those needed API calls will get implemented, help to point out to the WINE developers the exact API calls AutoCAD needs, or, implement them yourself. Also, if you're interested in joining WINE code contributors ranks, a guidance from programmers with more experience in the field of WINE development will save you a great deal of time.

Answer (score 11):

Also exist nice alternatives for hungry *Autodesk* products.

## FreeCAD

[***FreeCAD*** - A parametric 3D CAD modeler](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/free-cad/index.php?title=Main_Page)

just **free** and just **available for all major operating systems**.

[image: FreeCAD Screenshot, FreeCAD courtesy]

---

## Q-CAD

Other one is more than ten times cheaper than AutoCAD and it is very handy software:
[***Q-CAD Community Edition*** - Features](http://www.ribbonsoft.com/en/qcad-documentation/qcad-features) 
A professional 2d builder based on SVG manipulation and ECMAScript, which support DXF/DWG through 2010 version.

[image: Q-CAD on Linux]

---

## BRL-CAD

To full impress third one is [***BRL-CAD***](http://brlcad.org/), a powerful cross-platform open source solid modeling system that includes interactive geometry editing.

<sub>*... and his **Stryker ICV 8 trillions rays rendering** example :*</sub>

[image: Stryker ICV 8 trillions rays rendering]

---

*Update:*

## DraftSight

[DraftSight - Overview](http://www.3ds.com/products/draftsight/overview/)
Professional CAD software.

[image: DraftSight Screenshot by Ricky Jordan]

Comment: ok!I can see something here!Very helpfull for now!Look as i am studying architecture i am being learned exact programms mainly from autodesk as i mentioned before!Other programs like rhino3d is very necessary for me!So as i can see you have a knowledge that can help me!I also have managed to install Maya 2012 on my ubuntu so i have a nice workflow generally here!But i am trying to hard to decide -->windows or linux for my architectural visualization workflow?For example i need seriusly fast switches between programms with the same dwg file,import and exporting!So what do you suggest?

Comment: obviously such situation mentions to prefer reliability over than features due to very special quality of Architecture as is such workflow able to be fundamental in some projects.

So financial parameter should not decide something here and if it enough to build reliable system on windows means that perhaps we should use this secure way :) and no more.

however, Maya solves many things on Linux when stable version used (for now it's 11.10) Probably needed just provide software compliance with safety using shared resources as is memory, program dependencies, common filesystem permissions.

Comment: Try FreeCAD. One of his features it is "An Assembly module that allows to work with multiple shapes, multiple documents, multiple files, multiple relationships..."

Comment: Just very difficult to suggest finitely one solution.
If question need to have some long term solution probably we should avoid instabilities carefully more.

Comment: Just to discuss here, http://yorik.uncreated.net/guestblog.php?tag=blender&complete=3 this is a link of an architect who uses linux!Very helpfull all of his information.So i think that i should learn all this staff even freecad is a bit of difficult no tutorials, no automatic updates and also it is version 0.12!!so?i think i should learn obviusly blender and then pass all the data to maya for renders and animations and pass data to freecad too for 2D  presantation and then to a to 2D programm like bricscad or ares commander!makes sense right?

Comment: Could you help more so we can pass the information on a blog or something after all this?

Comment: Agree, Blender is multipurpose number one, sure. It's even more over than just fill this gap. However, situations can be different and not always point to conclude some workflow rigidness. Many ways for different goals is logically reliable method. Though also not always can be comfortable for all bunch of targets. Just as way. Like philosophy. Like Ubuntu! :)

Comment: Any idea on how to run brl-cad after installation?Also what do you say about passing our own experience on a blog or something?Are you interested in helping me?

Comment: Read _POST-INSTALLATION_ part in **Installation Instructions** at [BRL-CAD Documentation](http://brlcad.org/wiki/Documentation)

Comment: umhm ... Thank you for offer @gabriel So many ways to help each other. What words you want thats should be said? You ask me for my time which is a big deficit. What thing can shy this gap? ... It's all the rhetoric only. I try to help you here. Perhaps I've can do more over. No one knows. Out of offers it can be just rhetoric art. But with it - it more similar like harassing people. Thank you for this thought.

Comment: well, then you will have to keep helping me!:-)

Comment: I will have to spend a lot of time to achieve this thing.I dont have all the necessary knowledge!Any idea on where to ask for more help?Maybe changing the title?Or moving to any other forum?Thanks Swift!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3094/discussion-between-swift-and-gabriel)

Answer (score 1):

Did you know about playonlinux program? It's a program to do scripts that can achieve install windows programs(also games) in ubuntu. All of his scripts are based on wine and his tricks.

You can go to its project page and ask questions or learn about how to make scripts.
http://www.playonlinux.com/en/

If you ask the difference between wine an playonlinux:
[The connection of Wine and PlayOnLinux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7269/the-connection-of-wine-and-playonlinux)

Comment: yes,but playonlinux has only SOME versions of programms.How can i install manually a programm via pol?Ok, i understand, i have to ask somewhere else,right?Now, what help should i wait for this problem?

Comment: you can install a program that is not listed.
To do that click install, then below left you will find a "install non listed program". Now you have to configure wine, etc. to install a program...I don't know how to install autocad and if it is possible, but you can try it there...and the best thing is that you can configure which version of wine, which tricks, etc.  you use for each program you install in POL.

Comment: swift, draftsight is nice BUT has no dynamic input and has no good connections and configurations with printers!So, i prefer bricscad especially V12 but is not free and i have not  already configured the displaying of units.When i woom the arrows are way too big!If you know some about it,,,,,thanks

Comment: In the other post you wrote about workflows or something,did you mean?

Comment: Swift, any other help for me?Can you give or not?thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. I tought that you are commenting in the wrong answer. Click more above to comment in the answer of draftsigth, etc. =)