# SVN - How to downgrade svn client version from 1.7.9 to 1.4.6

Tags: 12.04, svn

I want to downgrade my subversion client from **1.7.9 to 1.4.6**

Can someone tell me the way to downgrade it?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: SVN version of my online server is 1.4.6 and I am configuring on my new ubuntu setup - my ubuntu is having version 1.7.9. I don't want to upgrade svn version on server - It will be the last option :)

Comment: It should be backward compatible...

Answer (score 1):

I looked around on subversion's website and I was unable to find any .deb files for older versions available on the site (though it is possible I missed it).

What you can do instead is download the source from here: https://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/

Note that there is the source tarball and then the `*-deps` tarball.

If you're unsure of what to do with these files, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source)

If you do go this route, before you start, make sure you do `sudo apt-get purge subversion` to make sure it's uninstalled and doesn't leave any files that may conflict with the package you built from source