# Can't install apps via Software Center, the "use this souce" button does nothing

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I've got to admit that I'm new to using Ubuntu, but I can't find a good answer elsewhere... Here goes.

I'm still setting up a LiveUSB copy of Ubuntu with some new apps, but I can't get many of them to work. . . Scratch that, I haven't installed any at all yet.

The first thing I did was download a DEB copy of Atom.IO from the internet. It's a port of a really nice text editor that I use for HTML and CSS. However, when I open it, the Software Center opens up instead. Guessing that I'm supposed to hit "install", I do the obvious, but nothing happens other than the little animation. I click, it sinks in, it pops out again, nothing changed. Huh. There's also an RPM package, but I'm not sure what to do with that but that's another question... Anyway, I tried to get Chrome, but the exact same thing happened.

I also tried to download WINE from the 'Center, because it's supposed to emulate Windows software (right?), but I have a similar problem. I get a "Use this source" button that does nothing. I'm kinda frustrated by this.

What am I supposed to do? Am I doing something wrong, or missing something?

Comment: Added it as an answer. To install tarballs, refer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install downloaded deb packages using `dpkg`.

In fact, the software center acts as a front-end to `dpkg` while installing deb packages.

To install, type the command -

`sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb`

where 'file' is the name of the deb package.