# rebuild ubuntu from source, is it possible? How?

Tags: apt, compiling, source-code, cross-compilation

I want to rebuild Ubuntu for another hardware. So I'm wondering if there is any way to get the current stable source code for all software locally installed on my computer and recompiled them with cross compilation? For RPMs it is quite a simple task - install source packages and do cross-compilation with setting destination root folder. Is it possible to do the same 'trick' with Ubuntu/Debian package system?

Comment: @user535733 Thank you. Can you elaborate your answer with some examples and basic commands? I happy to accept your answer. I'm quite new with Debian.

Comment: It is possible, but it is easier with Linux from scratch or Gentoo . Unless you are going to make changes to the source code or configure options it is not worth the time and if you are, gentoo makes it easier to micromanage

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source

Comment: @Panther, Thank you for the suggestion. I built few  Linux servers and desktops using Linux from scratch in past. But it is a process (0_0). I have a funny feeling that preconfigured packages will be much easier to build. At least on my old OpenSUSE it was really few commands in the command line and several days of waiting.

Comment: Gentoo is easier imo. And if you are not changing anything or patching you get the exact same binary as is already in the repos, just FYI. Gentoo is easier than LFS you might look into it

Comment: @Panther thanks a lot for the advice. Let me take a look. I've never built Gentoo.