# Arasan Chess Engine for Ubuntu

Tags: chess

Can anyone explain me the procedure for installing the Arasan Chess Engine from this link: https://www.arasanchess.org/downld.shtml and using it to run with Eboard.

It would be nice if there is a step by step answer.

After extracting the .tar.gz file, when i give the make command it doesn't seem to run. Not sure, how to make the chess engine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing applications from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the procedure that I have followed just now and I think it is working.
First download arasan from the website. You can download the binary or source. In this case I downloaded the binary. Next put the downloaded file in a convenient location, extract it. After that, install `xboard`:

```
$ sudo apt install xboard
```

After that, open a terminal and run this command:

```
$ xboard -cp -fcp "PATH-TO-EXTRACTED-FOLDER/arasanx-64 -H 100M -c 2"
```

Here, replace the `PATH-TO-EXTRACTED-FOLDER` with the location where you have extracted the compressed file. For example, I keep these stuffs in `~/Applications` folder, so on my machine it looks like this: `xboard -cp -fcp "/home/u33how/Appications/arasan-linux-binaries-21.4/arasanx-64 -H 100M -c 2"` . Make the required modification.
Finally, play the game. 
Reference:
[github repo doc link](https://github.com/jdart1/arasan-chess/tree/master/doc)

Comment: Any idea how to use the engine with eboard? What do you mean by binary or source. I mean i downloaded the tar.gz file

Comment: Open the link in your question, you will see several options. For linux, there are 2 options: 1. `Linux/Mac source(tarball)` or 2. `Linux chess engine binaries + book` . I downloaded the second one. Rignt now I don't know how to use it with eboard. I hope this was helpfull

Comment: Yeah sure this was useful +1.  This is the error which i am getting Gtk-Message: 16:25:42.876: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: 16:25:42.883: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Comment: Error when trying to run with eboard. Note i downloaded the tar.gz file

Comment: Best guess, you are missing the 32 bit libraries. Try running this: ``` $ 

sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
 ``` Reference https://askubuntu.com/a/872397/929226

Comment: Emm. Those 2 errors have vanished. Now it's saying localhost permission denied

Comment: Sorry, without details I really cannot tell how to solve this. Best guess, you have to change a permission somewhere. Or maybe some other process is using the same localhost and port. If you can tell me what you did exactly, I might be able to help.

Comment: Sure. Downloaded arasan source from the website. Then extracted the .tar.gz file. Then ran the command in the terminal as you gave xboard ..... That's all i did

Comment: Not sure if this will work. Try this: go to the extracted folder, open your terminal, and run this: ``` $ chmod +x arasanx-64 ``` This command makes the target file executable. Good luck.

Comment: emm its says no such file

Comment: It's because wrong directory.I think you have extracted the source code, but I was working with the binary (download link: http://www.arasanchess.org/arasan-linux-binaries-21.4.tar.gz ) Sorry for the miss communication. In case of source code, you have to install it properly. I am not expert with source, so I really cannot help much, so I used the binary. Please download the binary and try again.

Comment: Yes i already told you that i extracted the tar.gz file. Let me try with the binary

Comment: um... the other one is also a tar.gz file

Comment: No issues, i said i downloaded the source :P Please the 8th comment :0

Comment: Working. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Also how do i add arasan as an engine in xboard? Because each time going to terminal and typing this command would be tough. If i add arasan as an engine then i can play black set the time limit etc etc without any difficulty. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know right now.

Comment: Thank you for the kind help