# Can I install AutoCad civil 3d through wine in my ubuntu 14.04.2?

Tags: software-installation

If yes , then how to install autocad civil 3d in ubuntu 14.04 through wine ?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this:
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/121528/how-to-get-autocad-working-with-wine>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely TRY to install it. Sometimes it may even install completely. But it never works. Most times it won't even start at all. For more details on actual trails, please visit winehq.org . I have tried to install many Autodesk products in Ubuntu over the years. Especially Autocad (many versions). Sadly, Autocad will never work in linux, because it heavily relies on Windows Registry for keeping values of its' sysvars (system variables).
There is some hope though: Autocad runs on MacOS, which is a BSD-based OS. BSD and linux are like cousins in the OS world. Autocad 360 runs on Android. And Android is linux!! Maybe in the next decade, hopefully, will see Autocad running natively on linux desktop. Somehow. Someday.