# Playing a Specific Game on Steam

Tags: steam

I installed Steam through my software center in order to play just one game. It is called "The Fall of Gods". It was only added to steam a few months ago, so I am not sure if I can even play it on Linux.

What do I need to do to make the game playable on Linux or to check if it is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more general approach on how to find out if any specific game will be playable on Ubuntu. It also is the approach I take before I buy a game for my kids.

1. **Check the system requirements on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com)**

   - A game that has a native Linux support will mostly run without issues provided we have an appropriate graphic card and driver. This will be listed like that in Steam:
     [image]
   - For the game in questions it will tell us it is designed for `XP,7,8,10` **only**, i.e. it will not run natively on Ubuntu/[Steam for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-install-steam).
2. **See if it is listed in the [AppDB to run under Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/) or Steam on Wine**

   - Anything rated "Platinum" or "Gold" will be playable. Games rated "Silver" may need special hacks, or may not fully run. Games rated "Bronce" or even "Garbage" will not run.
   - You game in question was not listed. So we don't really know whether it will run or not. It may still run but you'd have to try out by yourself.
   - Sometimes you will get a better support for running a given game through [playonlinux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7269/the-connection-of-wine-and-playonlinux).
   - Windows Steam games requires the Windows version of [Steam to be installed with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462030/can-i-play-windows-game-using-wine-and-or-through-steam). You can share your Steam account for both, Linux, and Windows versions.
3. **Google for other people's experince with running that game on Linux.**

   - This is a rather tedious approach as it may reveal may irrelevant results, including reports such as your question that were never answered. If we do not find anything (such as in your case) we still don't know.

In case I do not find any positive records on a given game to run in my Ubuntu-only environment I simply will not buy it.

Comment: I tried to get playonlinux but the command code did not work

Comment: You can install playonlinux through the software center or [click here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playonlinux) (from Playonlinux we can also install Steam).

Answer (score 2):

The game is [listed as](http://store.steampowered.com/app/424170/) Windows only on Steam.
You won't be able to download it through Steam for Linux.

You can [install Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) (and then [install the Windows version of Steam on Wine](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux#Step_1:_setting_up_Wine)) and download the game though that. This *might* work. It's not a very popular game so there are [no reports](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=The%20fall%20of%20gods%20appdb) as to whether or not this works yet.

Some games just never work through Wine. Some work fine.

Comment: How would I install the windows version thru wine when i press install it does not give me a exe file i am sorry I am not that smart I rely on the internet for everything thanks much for the help @Oli

Comment: You will need to download and install Steam for Windows using wine.

Comment: Yes i know that but I only know how to install thru soft ware center idk how to get the exe file @JavierRivera

Comment: @streak You go to steampowered.com and download the EXE file, just like you would do on Windows. Then follow Oli's guides.

Comment: @Zacharee1 when i press install steam it does not give me the EXE file

Comment: Looking right below the big install button, I found the link for Windows: https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/SteamSetup.exe

Comment: @Zacharee1 installed it but i just keep getting errors and it closes :(

Comment: Write up a new question about it with the errors you get. Include as much detail as possible, even if you don't think it's completely relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it on the Steam [website](http://store.steampowered.com/app/424170/). No need to install anything.

And the answer is no. It's Windows only.

Comment: But isn't there a way to play windows games on linux?

Comment: Not in Steam and none really reliable or easy.

Comment: Using virtual machine might be of help...